# how to upload video to facebook page using php sdk and api graph 2.6

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

I'm trying to use [facebook-graph-api-v2.6](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to upload video in mp4 format supplying source equal to the link of the video where it has been upload to a web server but I'm getting this error

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 390,
    "error_subcode": 1363030,
    "is_transient": true,
    "error_user_title": "Video Upload Time Out",
    "error_user_msg": "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "BjhWMaUVuR1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.`
Can you try with a small file?

Comment: I'm uploading from web server and its size is 856 KB only.

Comment: cam you share the full code how you are sending the file?

Comment: Right now I'm only using the [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to upload video but I'm unable to figure out [Uploading Videos with the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads) then I will implement it using facebook-php-sdk-v5

Comment: okay. try and see if that works. all the best.

Comment: If you're "rolling your own" solution or upgrading a legacy SDK, you'll get this error message if you provide the upload data in the wrong field or format.  For us, the fix was making sure we were using `new CurlFile()` for `source`.  Might be something to check!  [(Related)](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/504112269933280/)